# Apache URL Rewriting issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i've set the rules,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ user.php?userid=$1
```

it redirects http://localhost/username to http://localhost/user.php?id=username works fine,
but for other existing folder page still redirects to user.php page; not that existing folder, ex http://localhost/folder it still redirects to http://localhost/folder/?userid=folder,
how can it make it to work for existing directories, ex when i type http://localhost/folder then page should shown of /folder/ directory ???

Comment: hmmmm. but not working it stil goes to `http://localhost/folder/?userid=folder` instead of actually `http://localhost/folder/` (the actual folder)

Comment: Add the `Options -MultiViews` option.

Comment: It is not good to use rewriterule like this. This redirection means that anything after localhost will redirect to user.php

Comment: Please show the .htaccess file that lies within `/folder` (if available) and other directives from the apache configuration that are active for the directories in your question.

Comment: i've edited question and the .htaccess file is only in root, there is not .htaccess file in `/folder` directory.

Comment: Code looks fine. Try adding a `RewriteBase /`.

Comment: Still Getting problem unsolved ..... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your .htaccess code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(messages)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(A-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ user.php?userid=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

If it still doesn't work please post matching long entries from access.log and enable RewriteLog in your httpd.conf and post logs from there in your question.

Comment: i've edited my question; actually i wrote `RewriteRule ^messages/?$ index.php?page=messages [L,NC]` rule before the line `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ user.php?userid=$1 [L,NC,QSA] ` removing the `RewriteRule ^messages/?$ index.php?page=messages [L,NC]` it works fine, this line creates problem, so how to overcome this problem. the final .htaccess file is as my edited question.

Comment: Please check my edited answer based on your comment and edited question.

Comment: ok great. thanks for your answer, and make my doubhts clear. have nice day .... :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your second RewriteRule has no RewriteConds. Your two RewriteConds only apply for the first rule, then they stop. The second rule therefore applies unconditionally to every request URI.
So this part of your .htaccess should look like this instead:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^messages/?$ index.php?page=messages [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ user.php?userid=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: does RewriteConds applies for only one rule ?